# AWS S3 change the file extension when using putObject(String,String,String)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to using AWS's S3 and I have to upload a file using the `putObject(bucket name, key , string that will become the file)` method (makes my life a lot easier).  I was wondering if it's possible to change the extension because when I use this method the file uploaded always has a '.txt' extension, but I need it to be '.csv'.

The code is quite simple:

```
public void uploadStringFile(String bucket,String username, String fileString) {
    s3Client.putObject(bucket, username, fileString);
}

awsS3Service.uploadStringFile("ati-teste",fileName, sb.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry i Forgot to mention i'm using Java.

Comment: In the [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) class there is no such method.  This is the primary class you use to interact with S3.  So where is `uploadStringFile` coming from?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I forgot i made an interface to integrate the S3 to my existing project. I am actually using the putObject method. The one that you use 3 Strings as input, the last one being the file itself.

Comment: But the second argument in that method is the key - AWS doesn't care what the file name was initially - as stored in the File, but what the key is.  How are you generating the key? We really need to see some of your source code - that's why you're getting down voted.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i  figured it wasn't necessary since the code was quite simple. My doubt is if i can change the file extension if i use the putObject method with three Strings as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the signature for your helper `uploadStringFile` method:

```
public void uploadStringFile(String bucket,String username, String fileString)
```

The parameter names are potentially misleading.  We see that the code delegates to [`AmazonS3#putObject(String, String, String)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
s3Client.putObject(bucket, username, fileString);
```

According to its JavaDocs, the parameters are:

> Parameters:
>
> bucketName - The name of the bucket to place the new object in.
>
> key - The key of the object to create.
>
> content - The String to encode

Notice there is no `username`.  Instead, the second parameter is the destination `key`.  Therefore, you can simply pass whatever key you want in the second parameter, and that's where it will go in S3.  If you already have a base file name like "test1.txt", then you can use basic [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) operations to change it to "test1.csv" before calling the S3 method.

Note that you also might find it more convenient to use other variants of the S3 API, such as [`AmazonS3#putObject(String, String, File)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) or [`AmazonS3#putObject(PutObjectRequest)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-) in a form like this:

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucket)
        .withKey(key)
        .withFile(inputFileObject));
```

Comment: Yeah  the second parameter i'm using the username becaus on my environment i'll use the username + date since it's some kind of a log that i'm uploading to S3. I've tried setting the name to exemple.csv, and it doesnt seem to work, it ends up as "exemple.csv.txt". Everything is working fine the only problem is that it saves as txt and not csv as intended. Thanks for the help I'm using string because i take the data from a list and turning it into a Sring. Sorry if the question wasn't well thought or clarifying enough.